Matlab fill function
I am trying to fill the area between the variable b (size 7301x1) and the minimum value of zaxis (size of zaxis is 1x1376, but I only want to use the minimum value of it) for xaxis (size 7301x1). I attempted the following code:
xfill = [xaxis, fliplr(xaxis)];
yfill = [min(zaxis) * ones(size(b)), b];
fill(xfill, yfill, 'r');

The code ran successfully, but it only filled the area for b, creating a triangle shape at the location of b and a separate horizontal line at the minimum zaxis. I would like to fill the area between the horizontal line and the plot of b. How can I achieve this?
I also tried using the patch function, but I got the same result. I’m pretty sure I missed something, but I have no idea what.
I tried
xfill = [xaxis, fliplr(xaxis)];
yfill = [min(zaxis) * ones(size(b)), b];
patch(xfill, yfill, 'r');

I want to fill the area between min(zaxis) and b.

I have no idea how the backslashes ended up there. I was struggling to insert code since this was my first time asking a question, so I’m pretty sure I messed something up. The code is from MATLAB. I’ve fixed it now, thank you!

I think you just need to swap the order of concatenation for yfill, since you want b to align with xaxis in the original order and you can align fliplr(xaxis) with the min zaxis values.
xfill = [xaxis, fliplr(xaxis)];
yfill = [b, min(zaxis)*ones(size(b))];
patch(xfill,yfill,'r');

For some dummy example:
xaxis = linspace(0,10,7301);
zaxis = rand( 1, 1376 ) - 1;
b = sin( xaxis ) + xaxis;
xfill = [xaxis, fliplr(xaxis)];
yfill = [min(zaxis)*ones(size(b)), b];
patch(xfill,yfill,'r');



Hi Wolfie,
Thank you for your comment. Your example is exactly what I’m trying to do! However, when I changed the order of yfill (min(zaxis) * ones(size(b))and b), it gave me the same result.
At first, I wondered if MATLAB might be confused because min(zaxis) is a constant value, but based on your example, I guess that’s not the issue.
Could it be that the problem arises because b is not defined as an equation?

I changed to
xfill = [xaxis; flipud(xaxis)];
yfill = [b; min(zaxis)*ones(size(b))];
patch(xfill,yfill,'r');
And it filled the area in between! Your comment gave me an idea. Thank you!
